# Which HTTP headers are set by the web browser and sent automatically

Tags: http, browser, https, http-headers

I am assuming that all web browsers send `User-Agent`, `DNT`, `Accept`, `Accept-Language`, `Accept-Encoding` etc automatically. The web developer do not have to do anything to set these headers. I am saying this because previously `www.whatismybrowser.com` used to show these header values.

If so then which headers are set by the web browser and sent automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP here. I got the answer from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/km9jh8/which_http_headers_are_set_by_the_web_browser_and/ghdk6m0?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

One thing you could easily do is create a page like `test.php` and set it to just:

```
<?php
print_r($_SERVER);
```

Then visit that in the different browser and OS combos that you care about and take any of the notes that you're looking for.